# How to style specific child tags in css

Tags: html, css

I am styling chat layout and got stuck at the point . This is my snippet

https://jsfiddle.net/9ce1d8or/

```css
#chatbox {
  background: #f7f7f7;
  padding: 10px;
}
#chatbox #chatmessages {
  max-height: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
}
#chatbox #chatmessages .messages {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#chatbox #chatmessages .messages .message {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
#chatbox #chatmessages .messages .message.message-received {
  background: green;
  margin: 5px 0;
  max-width: 40%;
}
#chatbox #chatmessages .messages .message.message-sent {
  float: right;
  margin: 5px 0;
  background: #ccc;
  max-width: 40%;
}

.clearfix::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="chatbox">
    <div id="chatmessages" class="">
         <div class="messages" >
                   <div class="product"></div>
                  <div class="message message-received">Hello </div>
                  <div class="message message-sent">Hello mrs </div>
                  <div class="clearfix"></div>  
                  <div class="message message-sent">Hello mrs </div>    
                  <div class="message message-received">Hello </div>
                  <div class="message message-received">Hello </div>
         </div><!--.messages-->
      <div class="messages" >
                  <div class="product"></div>
                  <div class="message message-received">Hello </div>
                  <div class="message message-sent">Hello mrs </div>
                  <div class="clearfix"></div>  
                  <div class="message message-sent">Hello mrs </div>    
                  <div class="message message-received">Hello </div>
                  <div class="message message-received">Hello </div>
         </div><!--.messages-->
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to style every first `.message-received` which is child of `.messages` element. Tried all pseudo selectors but nothing worked as expected. I have tried 
`.messages .message-received::first-of-type`, `::nth-of-type(2)`
Is the markup style correct for what i want to style? or i am doing wrong with css? Your suggestions will be very helpful.

Comment: have you tried `:first-child`?

Comment: You mean you want to style the first hello for instance??

Comment: yes but not working

Comment: Yes i want to style the first .message-received class of  .messages container @FridayAmeh

Comment: You may wanna give this a look https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`first-child` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child) (like the name is suggesting) selects the first child of an element - in your case that would be the element of class `.product`.
There is no first child of class `.message-received` in your markup, thatswhy that selector doesn't work for your case.

To select the first element of a specific class, you would do a little trick. First style all elements of that class with the first class styles and then revert the styles for all siblings, using the [adjacent sibling selector `~`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors):

```css
#chatbox #chatmessages .messages .message-received {
  background: red;
}
#chatbox #chatmessages .messages .message-received ~ .message-received {
  background: green;
}
```

This way, the first element of the class will be styled:

```css
#chatbox {
  background: #f7f7f7;
  padding: 10px;
}

#chatbox #chatmessages {
  max-height: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
}

#chatbox #chatmessages .messages {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#chatbox #chatmessages .messages .message {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

#chatbox #chatmessages .messages .message.message-received {
  background: red;
  margin: 5px 0;
  max-width: 40%;
}

#chatbox #chatmessages .messages .message.message-sent {
  float: right;
  margin: 5px 0;
  background: #ccc;
  max-width: 40%;
}

.clearfix::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

#chatbox #chatmessages .messages .message-received ~ .message-received {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="chatbox">
  <div id="chatmessages" class="">
    <div class="messages">
      <div class="product"></div>
      <div class="message message-received">Hello </div>
      <div class="message message-sent">Hello mrs </div>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
      <div class="message message-sent">Hello mrs </div>
      <div class="message message-received">Hello </div>
      <div class="message message-received">Hello </div>
    </div>
    <!--.messages-->
    <div class="messages">
      <div class="product"></div>
      <div class="message message-sent">Hello mrs </div>
      <div class="message message-received">Hello </div>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
      <div class="message message-sent">Hello mrs </div>
      <div class="message message-received">Hello </div>
      <div class="message message-received">Hello </div>
    </div>
    <!--.messages-->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what if .message-sent class is before the .message-received class? This is chat layout and i can't predict which class is used first .

Comment: ok, updated my answer accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uygynzcw/)

```
.messages > .message-received {
  background: pink;
}

.messages > .message-received ~ .message-received {
  background: none;
}
```

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class), it's the first (accepted) answer.
The idea is to select all elements with the same class, and then "deselect" all the elements with the same class that come after the first one.

```css
.messages > .message-received {
  background: pink;
}

.messages > .message-received ~ .message-received {
  background: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="chatbox">
  <div id="chatmessages" class="">
    <div class="messages">
      <div class="product"></div>
      <div class="message message-received">Hello* </div>
      <div class="message message-sent">Hello mrs </div>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
      <div class="message message-sent">Hello mrs </div>
      <div class="message message-received">Hello </div>
      <div class="message message-received">Hello </div>
    </div>
    <!--.messages-->
    <div class="messages">
      <div class="product"></div>
      <div class="message message-received">Hello* </div>
      <div class="message message-sent">Hello mrs </div>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
      <div class="message message-sent">Hello mrs </div>
      <div class="message message-received">Hello </div>
      <div class="message message-received">Hello </div>
    </div>
    <!--.messages-->
  </div>
</div>
```